# multiple characters replacements in string php

Tags: php, php-5.6

Let's say that I have the following string:

```
$string = 'xxyyzz';
```

And then I have a substitution array like this:

```
$subs = ['xy'];
```

Meaning that every **x** should be replaced by **y** in my string and every **y** should be replaced by **x**. Let's say that my substitution array can only contain pairs of characters to be replaced in my **$string**.

How would I go about doing this?

I tried using **str_replace** the following way but that doesn't work:

```
foreach ($subs as $sub) {
    $sub_arr = str_split($sub);
    $reversed_sub_arr = array_reverse($sub_arr);

    $output = str_replace($sub_arr, $reversed_sub_arr, str_split($string));
}

$output = implode('', $output);
```

But the output gives me **xxxxzz**

The output should be **yyxxzz**

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

This working for your case

```
  $string = 'xxyyzz';
$subs = ['xy'];
foreach ($subs as $sub) {
    $sub_arr = str_split($sub);

    $output = strtr($string, array($sub_arr[0]=>$sub_arr[1], $sub_arr[1]=>$sub_arr[0]));

}
echo $output; //yyxxzz
```

Comment: Hi. This works if I have only one item in array subs, what if I have two items like $subs = ['xy', 'dz'] where x should be replaced by y, y whould be replaced by x, d should be replaced by z and z should be replaced by d

Comment: That works too,before ->xxyyzzdd
                     after swap xxyyddzz

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Orgil answer if two items in `$subs` array like `$subs = ['xy', 'dz']`

```
$string = $output = 'xxyyzz';
$subs = ['xy', 'dz'];
foreach ($subs as $sub) {
    $sub_arr = str_split($sub);

    $output = strtr($output, array($sub_arr[0]=>$sub_arr[1], $sub_arr[1]=>$sub_arr[0]));

}
echo $output;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/L4KQa)